# Add phtml to Customer Account Edit in Adminhtml

Tags: magento2, layout, customer-account, phtml, custom-block

I tried to add phtml to customer account edit in backend like this:

***app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit" name="customer_block_adminhtml_index_edit_custom" cacheable="false" template="Namespace_Module::customer_index_edit.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

***app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit.php***

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $viewHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

***app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/customer_index_edit.phtml***

```
<h1> This is new section </h1>
```

but this is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new tab, it's not too much work.

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View\Custom"
                   name="customer_edit_tab_view_custom"
                   template="Staempfli_Agreements::customer/view/custom.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/View/Custom.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\View;

class Custom extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Custom Label');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Custom Label');
    }
}
```

Add your phtml file and that's it.